# Display npm audit vulnerabilities in html format

Tags: node.js, npm, report

Is there a way to display the npm audit report as an html page?

At the moment i can only see the option to output the report in json format, using this command:

`npm audit --json`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I wrote an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-audit-html) that does this for you.

You can use it by running the following:

```
// first install it
npm i -g npm-audit-html

// then pipe npm audit to it
npm audit --json | npm-audit-html
```

Comment: I saw the download stats on npm, I wasn't the only one that wanted this feature. Well done.

Comment: Hi! Is It possible with your module to create one HTML report from multiple package.json in other subfolders?

Comment: I'm getting "no input" for some reason as a result - but npm audit --json definitely produces output..

Comment: @MarkZhukovsky Are you using PowerShell? If so, you may be seeing this issue. https://github.com/eventOneHQ/npm-audit-html/issues/34

Comment: I think you can use the > instead. npm audit --json > npm-audit-html

Comment: From a PowerShell prompt you need to pass the whole thing to cmd because PS won't pipe output between non-PS things `cmd /c 'npm audit --json | npm-audit-html'`

Answer (score 7):

npm-audit-html is a good package, just used it.

```
npm install -g npm-audit-html
npm audit --json | npm-audit-html --output report.html
```

If you are getting the "No Input" response when running through powershell or VS Code Terminal just run it with the command prompt

Comment: As of 9-Apr-20, the file created by npm-audit-html is named `npm-audit.html`.

Answer (score 7):

Following previous answers...
As of NPM v7, you'll need the beta version of `npm-audit-html`.

```
npm install -g npm-audit-html@beta
npm audit --json | npm-audit-html --output report.html
```

For more details: https://github.com/eventOneHQ/npm-audit-html/issues/43#issuecomment-940159989

P.S. Tested with NPM v8.3.0.

Comment: Thanks! I previously got 'No data available in table' and 0 dependencies in the html file. With the beta version, it's now working (using npm v8.9.0).

Comment: Was looking for a native way without installing any new dependency, but there doesn't seem to be any way to get HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux I'm using [ccat](https://github.com/jingweno/ccat) in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"/></head><body>"
npm audit|ccat --html
echo "</body></html>"
```

Usage: `./audit.sh > vulnerabilities.html`

But I'm also interested in other solutions, maybe ones that could work on Windows too.

Comment: I recommend Cygwin for windows/bash stuff.  So long as it's minor bash scripting.

Comment: Cygwin is nice but I would recommend msys2 (https://www.msys2.org/) as a more advanced solution.