# npm audit response shows up as just plain text instead of tabular format

Tags: node.js, npm, report, npm-audit

I read a lot of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68178057/7584240)/[articles](https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/issues/11676#issuecomment-463608025) related to `npm audit` where people have provided the response of the `npm audit` in a tabular format. But when I run the `npm audit` I get the response as plain text.

I tried to install a library `npm-audit-html` and get the format in HTML as provided in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53792610/7584240) but that is running into the issue: `zsh: command not found: npm-audit-html`

Can someone please explain and help in resolving the beautification of the `npm audit` response? Currently, my `npm audit` response shows up something like this:

```
postcss-overflow-shorthand  <=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-overflow-shorthand
  postcss-page-break  <=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-page-break
  postcss-place  <=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-place
  postcss-pseudo-class-any-link  <=6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link
  postcss-reduce-initial  <=4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-initial
  postcss-reduce-transforms  <=4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-transforms
  postcss-replace-overflow-wrap  <=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-replace-overflow-wrap
  postcss-selector-matches  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-matches
  postcss-selector-not  <=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-not
  postcss-svgo  <=5.0.0-rc.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
  node_modules/postcss-svgo
  postcss-unique-selectors  <=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-unique-selectors
  postcss-url  3.3.0 - 10.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-url
  stylehacks  <=4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/stylehacks

90 vulnerabilities (84 moderate, 6 high)
```

Comment: i hate to break it to you, but `npm audit --help` would have told you how it's done if that was an option. Perhaps there's an implementation difference between mac/linux/windows version of node? I'm not sure... what it does offer though is the `--json` parameter which is just as good as far as the shell scripts go. What do you really need it for?

Comment: @KamilJanowski Thanks a lot for the response. I am aware of the `--json` part but that would just display in `JSON` format. I am looking for some command or additional package which can beautify the `npm audit output`. I am using `Macos` for developing my application.

Answer (score 2):

In windows, I've used npm audit with ">" to write its content in a json file, refer below command:

```
npm audit --json > FOLDER_PATH\FILE_NAME.json
```

Answer (score 1):

The `npm audit` format you posted is a breaking change of npm 7.

> Output and data structure is significantly refactored to call attention to issues, identify classes of fixes not previously available, and remove extraneous data not used for any purpose.
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: Any tools consuming the output of npm audit will almost certainly need to be updated, as this has changed significantly, both in the readable and --json output styles.
>
> *Source: [npm release notes](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major)*

As the output format not officially explained, there is a [post](https://uko.codes/dealing-with-npm-v7-audit-changes) try to find it out. You can check the post for more details.